# What is the recommended way to access file inside test/resource folder from karate features file inside test/java/karate

Tags: spring-boot, classpath, karate

According to the documentation, classpath is app/test/java. So how to access the json files inside resources folder in spring-boot.

Comment: `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` are both part of the classpath.

Comment: Unfortunately, my classpath stopped recognising src/test/resources, which was working before. Can you share your pom.xml content mentioned here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#folder-structure

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Deinum, classpath can access folders in both

> src/test/java

> src/test/resources